# Is there any web api for Apple's Game Center?

Tags: web-services, game-center

I have a website. I was wondering if Apple exposed its Game Center data via a web api. If would be cool if I could show users their Game Center info right in my website!

Let me know folks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may still be under NDA as I had to log on to look at the game center docs...
I did find a non apple site with a [getting started pdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEQQFjAE&url=http://www.assembla.com/spaces/rp01/documents/bnaExqCkmr4legeJe5cbLr/download?filename=gettingstartedwithgamecenter.pdf&rct=j&q=game%20center%20service%20web%20api&ei=k-7STeD5D4zWtQOyktSlCQ&usg=AFQjCNF5vWtt37a4jIgmE_Jmpql-bMLPOw&sig2=cFI0POTkLEO8G5cvQGx-qw). it contains an interesting passage:

> The data maintained by the Game Center
>   service should only be used to provide
>   the services and functionality
>   necessary for your application, and
>   may not be transferred or copied to
>   other services. For example, you may
>   not download Game Center leaderboard
>   data to post on your app website or to
>   another service.