# Apple Game Center Web API

Tags: ios, api, itunes, game-center

I am not trying to integrate Game Center into an application, instead I am trying to pull leaderboards and achievements into my web page.

Is there an API or RSS feed for Game Center?

[Is there any web api for Apple's Game Center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055936/is-there-any-web-api-for-apples-game-center?rq=1) .  Any change in policy?  This policy limits the success/visibility of game center.

Comment: SO soldiers - feel free to downvote or mark as duplicate.  Just breathing new life into this topic.   Sometimes answers change..

Comment: Please see [How to bump a question that's the same as the one you wanted to ask?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1471)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Nope.

A [quick search on Google](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=game+center+RSS&oq=game+center+RSS&gs_l=hp.3...7978.8305.1.8567.3.3.0.0.0.0.80.234.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.m-MjgrQdCFY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.cGE&fp=c2f7fea773515bd2&biw=1280&bih=679) revealed no relevant content.

If there *was* an API/RSS Feed for this, I would expect it to come up in that search.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no publicly available web API for Game Center.